# In python3-flet script, how to remove a button after click?

Tags: python-3.x, macos, button, onclick, flet

I would like to remove a button when it's clicked.
Following my Python3-Flet script:

```
import flet as fl
def main(page:fl.Page):
    def remove(e):
        pass #what could i do for remove the button?
    page.add(fl.ElevatedButton('REMOVE ME',on_click=remove))
    page.update()
fl.app(target=main)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use e.control to remove your element. It helps to you to remove this button.

```
import flet as fl
def main(page:fl.Page):
    def remove(e):
        e.control.page.remove(e.control)
    remove_button = fl.ElevatedButton('REMOVE ME',on_click=remove)
    page.add(remove_button)
    page.update()
fl.app(target=main)
```

If you want to remove different element u can use

```
import flet as fl

def main(page: fl.Page):

    def remove(e):
        e.control.page.controls.remove(other_button)
        e.control.page.update()
    remove_button = fl.ElevatedButton('REMOVE ME', on_click=remove)
    other_button = fl.ElevatedButton("REMOVE THIS")
    page.add(remove_button, other_button)
    page.update()

fl.app(target=main)
```